# Farseer: Difficulties with implementation of DebugView

Tags: xna, c#, physics, farseer-physics-engine

I added the project "Farseer Physics Engine 3.3.1 HelloWorld XNA\DebugView XNA\DebugView XNA.csproj" to my solution explorer in Visual Studio. In addition, I added a reference to my project and the "using FarseerPhysics.DebugViews;" to my class.

But DebugView is still not working. I tried this code but I always get an error message and a warning. I found the code in a Farseer discussion: 
https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/discussions/275582

Error message:

```
'FarseerPhysics.DebugViews.DebugViewXNA' does not contain a definition for 'DebugPanel' and no extension method 'DebugPanel' accepting a first argument of type 'FarseerPhysics.DebugViews.DebugViewXNA' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Warning:

```
The referenced component 'DebugView XNA Content (Content)' could not be found.
```

What is this DebugPanel? What is wrong?

What should I change in my code?

Code:

```
World world;
DebugViewXNA physicsDebug;
DebugViewXNA DebugViewFlags;
physicsDebug = new DebugViewXNA(world);
physicsDebug.AppendFlags(DebugViewFlags.DebugPanel);
physicsDebug.DefaultShapeColor = Color.White;
physicsDebug.SleepingShapeColor = Color.LightGray;
physicsDebug.LoadContent(GraphicsDevice, Content);
```

Drawing DebugView:

```
 // calculate the projection and view adjustments for the debug view
        Matrix projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0f, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / _displayUnitsToSimUnitsRatio,
                                                         graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / _displayUnitsToSimUnitsRatio, 0f, 0f,
                                                         1f);
        Matrix view = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3((_cameraPosition / _displayUnitsToSimUnitsRatio) - (_screenCenter / _displayUnitsToSimUnitsRatio), 0f)) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3((_screenCenter / _displayUnitsToSimUnitsRatio), 0f));
        // draw the debug view
        physicsDebug.RenderDebugData(ref projection, ref view);
```

Comment: Sounds like you didn't include the Debug Content project along with the Debug project.

Comment: What is the Debug Content project? How can I implement it?

Comment: There is a DebugView Project, and a DebugView Content Project.  Similar to other XNA projects, you have your Game and your Content.  You should be able to add the DebugView Content Project.

Comment: I found a file named DebugViewXNA Content.contentproj in Farseer Physics Engine 3.3.1 HelloWorld XNA\DebugView XNA\Content  Is that the correct file? I tried to add it to my solution explorer, but I got a few warnings after adding it to the solution explorer. What is wrong? How can I fix the other error message(DebugPanel)?